# Strange Meteor Error

Tags: meteor

I know this may seem a little vague, but here goes.

I have started to receive the following error on restart and startup of my meteor application:

```
Exception from sub undefined Error
    at app/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js:50:44
    at /Users/me/projects/meteorapp/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:298:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/me/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:78:11)
    at run (/Users/me/projects/meteorapp/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:239:7)
```

The packages I have installed are:

```
{
  "meteor": {},
  "packages": {
    "router": {},
    "spin": {},
    "accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown": {},
    "roles": {},
    "user-status": {},
    "event-hooks": {},
    "sugarjs": {},
    "paginator": {},
    "momentjs": {},
    "collection-hooks": {},
    "jquery-ui": {},
    "collectionFS": {},
    "Mesosphere": {}
  }
}
```

I am using Meteor v 0.6.4.1.  I checked and made certain that my database doesn't have any duplicate entries.  Someone on IRC suggested that duplicate entries might be the cause of the error.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what may be causing this?

It appears that there is an error somewhere in my codebase.  Can anyone explain the error in any detail so that I might have better luck in tracking down the offending code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case, the issue appears to be with the **user-status** smart package. The error in particular was of this flavor:

```
{ name: 'MinimongoError', details: 'Duplicate _id \'bxFtQL4XjfrppD3hf\'' }
```

This occurs when the **user-status** code attempts to insert a document into `UserSessions`, but uses a specific `_id`, i.e. the value of `sessionId`. For whatever reason, this insert sometimes occurs more than once.  This `UserSessions` collection is instantiated with a `null` name in server code, which creates an in-memory collection. That helps explain why you saw a minimongo error message on the server.

I had to do some serious digging in order to have this error message show up. Otherwise, you get the very unhelpful stack trace you got.

Comment: Another thanks for tracking this down, as this is my code. [Issue is fixed on meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1246) but I will also add some tests and fix this soon.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a bug in the Mesosphere package, get in contact with the creator and mention the error https://github.com/copleykj/Mesosphere

Comment: I was in the wrong window looking at the output after removing packages.  It seems there's a bug someplace in my code.  That error message doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error as well. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/r6ENlLsrxoY

In my case it was because I was running a login in my Tinytest. Nothing was "wrong" but when I switched some things around, it went away.

I'm really not sure what is causing it, but I'm pretty sure it's a Meteor bug where the actual error is not being caught and reported correctly. We should report this.

I've filed an issue here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1246

EDIT: Ironically, was caused by an error from one of my own packages not being reported correctly. We'll get that fixed but the meteor issue fixed as well.